# How does an SQL Exists statement even work if the syntax is wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this SQL query work even though the `SELECT` is missing a `FROM`, which would be a syntax error. Also note that the query only shows the one that satisfies the `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Tbl
(
    CustomerName VARCHAR(50), 
    Address VARCHAR(250),
    Country VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Customer_Tbl 
VALUES
    ('AAA', '','Philippines'),
    ('BBB', '','Mexico'),
    ('CCC', '','Philippines'),
    ('DDD', '','Mexico'),
    ('EEE', '','Philippines');


SELECT *
FROM Customer_Tbl 
WHERE EXISTS(
    -- This is missing a FROM
    -- running it by itself is a syntax error.
    SELECT 2 Customer_Tbl 
    WHERE Country = 'MEXICO'
);
```

This is test on **SQL Server** 2012 and 2014, here's an online sample: http://rextester.com/GDGB80815

Comment: Question based on false assumption. The product doesn't report syntax errors when there are in fact no syntax errors.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't require `FROM` in the `SELECT` statement.

For example, there is no syntax error in the following query:

```
SELECT 2 AS t
WHERE 0 = 0
```

It returns one row with column `t` and value `2`.

You can write simple

```
SELECT 2 AS t
```

to get the same result.

---

Your query is the same as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer_Tbl 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 2 AS Customer_Tbl 
    WHERE Customer_Tbl.Country = 'MEXICO'
);
```

Inner `Customer_Tbl` is an alias for the column with the constant `2`. The `Country` in `WHERE` is a column of an outer table `Customer_Tbl`.

It is a good practice to use `AS` for aliases and fully qualify the columns with their table names.

---

When you try to run the inner part separately

```
SELECT 2 Customer_Tbl 
WHERE Country = 'MEXICO'
```

it fails not because there is no `FROM`, but because the parser doesn't know what is `Country`:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'Country'.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the syntax of `SELECT` statement in SQL Server from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

```
<SELECT statement> ::=    
    [ WITH { [ XMLNAMESPACES ,] [ <common_table_expression> [,...n] ] } ]  
    <query_expression>   
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] }   
  [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ <FOR Clause>]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]   
<query_expression> ::=   
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }   
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }  
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ]   
<query_specification> ::=   
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
    < select_list >   
    [ INTO new_table ]   
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ <GROUP BY> ]   
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

Optional clauses are in square brackets `[` `]`. As you can see, pretty much all clauses are optional, including `FROM`, except the `SELECT` keyword itself and `< select_list >`.

Answer (score 5):

It's valid. It's correlating back to `Customer_Tbl.Country`

If there is at least one record in `Customer_Tbl.Country='MEXICO'` then the WHERE EXISTS is TRUE

I'ts only valid when it's inside the `EXISTS` though

Comment: if you try completing the EXIST with `FROM Customer_Tbl` it will output a different result

Comment: @jbalintac That's because as your statement currently is, it's interpreting `Customer_Tbl` as a column alias. If you change it (adding `FROM` before `Customer_Tbl`), it will interpret `Customer_Tbl` as a table and the exists clause becomes entirely different.

Comment: Yes when you add `FROM Customer_Tbl` it's no longer correlating to the outside `Customer_Tbl`, the `EXIST` is always true regardless of what row is referred to in the outside `Customer_Tbl` so you get all rows